Running code at Flask startup, before requests
I'm trying to run some code at Flask startup, which uses the database (Flask-SQLAlchemy), but before any requests are taken.  I read that @app.before_first_request is deprecated, so what is the replacement.
If I don't use the database, it works. But using the database, I get RuntimeError: Working outside of application context..  I assume it's because the app hasn't been fully initialized yet
I have tried the following:
app.py
def create_app():
    nwm_app = Flask(__name__)
    nwm_app.config |= {
        "SQLALCHEMY_ENGINES": {
            "default": "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/flask_test"
        },
    }
    nwm_app.config.from_prefixed_env()
    db.init_app(nwm_app)
    alembic.init_app(nwm_app)

    on_start()

    # Register blueprints or views here
    nwm_app.register_blueprint(calibration)

    return nwm_app

on_start.py
def on_start():
    with current_app.app_context():
        with (db.session as session, session.begin()):
            query = select(table)
            result = session.execute(query)
            print('results', result)

The reason I need this is to do some database cleanup if the server previously ended abnormally
